# How can I list FDA approved drugs in a year?

Tags: openfda

I am trying to list all of the approved drugs in a particular year, (e.g. https://www.fda.gov/drugs/new-drugs-fda-cders-new-molecular-entities-and-new-therapeutic-biological-products/novel-drug-approvals-2021), but when I try going through the searchable fields I am not able to find anything relevant. How might I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The Drugs@FDA endpoint is likely the best to fit your needs. You would want to search for records with submission status of "*AP*" (approved). Also, you would want to look for submission types indicating a new drug application (for example, *Type 2 - New Active Ingredient*). Finally, if you know the year, you can filter by the submission status date falling into that year.

Here is an example for the year of 1981:

[openFDA API Call](https://api.fda.gov/drug/drugsfda.json?search=submissions.submission_status:%22AP%22%20AND%20(submissions.submission_class_code:%22TYPE%201%22%20OR%20submissions.submission_class_code:%22TYPE%201/4%22%20OR%20submissions.submission_class_code:%22TYPE%202%22%20OR%20submissions.submission_class_code:%22TYPE%202/3%22%20OR%20submissions.submission_class_code:%22TYPE%202/4%22%20OR%20submissions.submission_class_code:%22TYPE%204%22%20OR%20submissions.submission_class_code:%22TYPE%205%22%20OR%20submissions.submission_class_code:%22TYPE%203/4%22)%20AND%20submissions.submission_status_date:%5B1981-01-01%20TO%201981-12-31%5D)

Hopefully this helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if I try with submission_status: AP and submission_status_date. it would return supplemental submission approval records as well. but I need only original approvals made in that year. how I can filter supplement submissions?