# How can I list FDA approved drugs in a year? asked again

Tags: openfda

Does anyone figur this out?

[How can I list FDA approved drugs in a year?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/20063/how-can-i-list-fda-approved-drugs-in-a-year)

The answer stated the example for the year of 1981, and that call contains [1981-01-01+TO+1981-12-31].  So, I assumed that I should change to 2021.  However, what I got was "SYMTUZA" which is not on the list of approved drugs in 2021.

Here is the
[openFDA API call](https://api.fda.gov/drug/drugsfda.json?search=submissions.submission_status:%22AP%22%20AND%20(submissions.submission_class_code:%22TYPE%201%22%20OR%20submissions.submission_class_code:%22TYPE%201/4%22%20OR%20submissions.submission_class_code:%22TYPE%202%22%20OR%20submissions.submission_class_code:%22TYPE%202/3%22%20OR%20submissions.submission_class_code:%22TYPE%202/4%22%20OR%20submissions.submission_class_code:%22TYPE%204%22%20OR%20submissions.submission_class_code:%22TYPE%205%22%20OR%20submissions.submission_class_code:%22TYPE%203/4%22)%20AND%20submissions.submission_status_date:%5B2021-01-01%20TO%202021-12-31%5D) I used, and I was wrong. I got:REMICADE.

Still, I could not get a drug on the list of approved drugs in 2021.

One answer suggested to add a filter of submission_type:"ORIG". The follwing is the API call revised, I blieve, adding the filter.

[another openFDA API call](https://api.fda.gov/drug/drugsfda.json?search=submissions.submission_status:%22AP%22%20AND%20(submissions.submission_class_code:%22TYPE%201%22%20OR%20submissions.submission_class_code:%22TYPE%201/4%22%20OR%20submissions.submission_class_code:%22TYPE%202%22%20OR%20submissions.submission_class_code:%22TYPE%202/3%22%20OR%20submissions.submission_class_code:%22TYPE%202/4%22%20OR%20submissions.submission_class_code:%22TYPE%204%22%20OR%20submissions.submission_class_code:%22TYPE%205%22%20OR%20submissions.submission_class_code:%22TYPE%203/4%22)%20AND%20submissions.submission_status_date:%5B2021-01-01%20TO%202021-12-31%5D%20AND%20submissions.submission_type:%22ORIG%22)

I still get REMICADE, which is not on the list of drugs approved in 2021.

Comment: Could you give us the exact query you used or at least the parameter to get unlimited results? When I changed the stated query to 2021, I didn't get SYMTUZA (approved in 2018) at all, but it also didn't return all results.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment. If you visit

https://api.fda.gov/drug/drugsfda.json?search=symtuza

you'll see `results[0].submissions[0].submissionStatusDate = 20210611`

The URL you (probably) used was probably similar to:

[https://api.fda.gov/drug/drugsfda.json?search=submissions.submission_status:%22AP%22%20AND%20(submissions.submission_class_code:%22TYPE%201%22%20OR%20submissions.submission_class_code:%22TYPE%201/4%22%20OR%20submissions.submission_class_code:%22TYPE%202%22%20OR%20submissions.submission_class_code:%22TYPE%202/3%22%20OR%20submissions.submission_class_code:%22TYPE%202/4%22%20OR%20submissions.submission_class_code:%22TYPE%204%22%20OR%20submissions.submission_class_code:%22TYPE%205%22%20OR%20submissions.submission_class_code:%22TYPE%203/4%22)%20AND%20submissions.submission_status_date:[2021-01-01%20TO%202021-12-31]](https://api.fda.gov/drug/drugsfda.json?search=submissions.submission_status:%22AP%22%20AND%20(submissions.submission_class_code:%22TYPE%201%22%20OR%20submissions.submission_class_code:%22TYPE%201/4%22%20OR%20submissions.submission_class_code:%22TYPE%202%22%20OR%20submissions.submission_class_code:%22TYPE%202/3%22%20OR%20submissions.submission_class_code:%22TYPE%202/4%22%20OR%20submissions.submission_class_code:%22TYPE%204%22%20OR%20submissions.submission_class_code:%22TYPE%205%22%20OR%20submissions.submission_class_code:%22TYPE%203/4%22)%20AND%20submissions.submission_status_date:%5B2021-01-01%20TO%202021-12-31%5D)

Since you're filtering on the `submission_status_date` SYMTUZA will come up.

I think you need to add a filter for `submission_type = ORIG`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are right that the API call is too long for a comment.

Comment: I edited the original question, adding the exact query. The query returns "REMICADE", which is not on the list

Comment: OK, you've stumped me. Might be time to ping the FDA directly. Even the simpler query https://api.fda.gov/drug/drugsfda.json?search=submissions.submission_type:%22ORIG%22 returns SUPPL submission types.

Comment: Is there any way to "ping the FDA"? Actually, filtering "ORIG" submission type was also the question the original post [How can I list FDA approved drugs in a year?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/20063/how-can-i-list-fda-approved-drugs-in-a-year) asked in a comment. And, nobody responsed that.

Comment: It's generally considered bad form to ask the same question more than once and https://www.fda.gov/about-fda/contact-fda